# How to build a table in a form using DevDemon Forms?

Tags: forms, devdemon, devdemon-forms

I am trying to build a form for booking rooms using DevDemon Forms. The data I need to collect has a tabular format like this:

Room 1 name -- Date from -- Date to -- Time from -- Time to

How can I implement this using the said module? 
I have 5 columns so the 4 column layout widget does not work for this.

A solution would be to integrate a matrix field into forms - but I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using CSS. We provide a considerable amount of wrappers around each input field. Simply drag and drop the form fields you want and save the form. Then open your template and grab the ids of each wrapper. Then using divs you could float and/or inline-block them to work as columns.

Another option is you could just publish the form and grab the field names. Then using the tag pair you could just make your own fields and use whatever markup you want.  This makes it less "automated" but if you do not need the content admin to adjust the form, this could be an option as well.